# Storing values in hash of array more effectively

Tags: arrays, performance, perl, hash

I'm working on a script that generates large hash of arrays (HoAs) data structures. I'm trying to optimize my script because currently it's taking forever to run.

Recently I read from a site that one way you can further improve the speed of your script execution is to use a subroutine to store values in say a hash of arrays. It said it's especially great for large data structures.

Here's the example the article gave.

```
sub build_hash{
    # takes 3 params: hashref, name, and value
    return if not $_[2];

    push(@{ $_[0]->{'names'} }, $_[1]);
    push(@{ $_[0]->{'value'} }, $_[2]);

    # return a reference to the hash (smaller than making copy)
    return $_[0];
}
```

The article said calling this subroutine to build the HoA is **40% faster** than pushing values onto the hash of array outside of the subroutine. The subroutine is supposedly fast because it builds the data structure using references.

I would like to test this subroutine out by building my own HoA. Say I wanted to create the following hash of arrays.

```
%HoA = (
    'C1' =>  ['1', '3', '3', '3'],
    'C2' => ['3','2'],
    'C3' => ['1','3','3','4','5','5'],
    'C4'  => ['3','3','4'],
    'C5' => ['1'],
);
```

How would I implement build_hash to do this? Also, how would I call this subroutine?

Here's what I have but it's not quite working.

```
# let AoA be an array of arrays that contains the values I want to assign
# to each key in %HoA
my @AoA = (
            ['1', '3', '3', '3'],
            ['3','2'],
            ['1','3','3','4','5','5'],
            ['3','3','4'],
            ['1']
          );
my %HoA;
my $count = 1;

foreach my $ref (@AoA){
    build_hash(\%HoA, $ref, "C$count");
    $count++;
}

sub build_hash {
    # takes 3 params: hashref, arrayref, and key
    return if not $_[2];
    push(@{ $_[0]->{$_[1]} }, $_[2]);

    # return reference to HoA_ref (smaller than making copy)
    return $_[0];
 }
```

Comment: Here's the [LINK](http://www.slideshare.net/perrin_harkins/top-10-perl-performance-tips-11845463) to the article. It's the 18-19 slide of the powerpoint.

Comment: Calling a function in addition to doing X cannot possibly be faster than doing X, much less 40% faster.

Comment: Note that `%HoA = build_hash(\%HoA, $ref, "C$count");` makes no sense. It should be `build_hash(\%HoA, $ref, "C$count");`

Comment: You never place anything in `@AoA`, so your code consists of a loop that's never entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my %HoA; $HoA{"C$_"} = $AoA[$_-1] for 1..@AoA;
```

or

```
my %HoA; @HoA{ map "C$_", 1..@AoA } = @AoA;
```

or

```
my %HoA = map { "C$_" => $AoA[$_-1] } 1..@AoA;
```

Sorted from fastest to slowest (I think), but they're roughly all as fast as the other.

Comment: HoA is just an example of the type of data structures I want to build. In my script I do this multiple times. I actually compute the array_refs (in a separate subroutine) I want to assign to each key in HoA. Once I've built the HoA, I compare it with the value of each key in say HoA_intitial. Based on the comparisons, I compute new values to assign to the keys of HoA after emptying HoA. Then I do the comparison again to compute new values.

Comment: this seems a lot more efficient than how I originally thought of approaching it. thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm glad you liked my presentation, but I think the point of that slide didn't come across without the talk that went with it.  I was trying to show how directly accessing @_ instead of copying the contents into local variables can save a bit of time on a very frequently called and otherwise minimal sub.

It's unlikely that building the HoA is really the slow part of your program.  I would advise you to do what I did before making the change shown in my slide, which is to run Devel::NYTProf on your program and see where the time is going.  Then you'll know what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

That is *not* what those slides say at all. What Perrin is showing is a way to reduce the sub call overhead *assuming you need to have the subroutine at all*, because calling a subroutine takes time. You aren't going to make code faster by adding subroutines where they're not needed.